# Prove that det(AB) = det(A) det(B) in AB ∈ $GL_2(\mathbb{R} \!\,)$

Tags: group-theory, determinant

Prove that $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B) $ if $A,B \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. Use this result to show that
the binary operation in the group $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is closed; that is, if $A $ and $ B$ are
in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, then $AB \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

I am totally stuck, I know these things to be true but I don't know how to show that. Any tips on how to get started?

Comment: $\text{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all $2 \times 2$ invertible matrices. So let $$A = \begin{bmatrix}a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$B = \begin{bmatrix}a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2 & d_2 \end{bmatrix}\text{,}$$such that the components of $A$ and $B$ are defined so that they are invertible. From here, it depends on how you define the determinant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d  \\
\end{array} \right)$ and $B=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x & y \\
z & t  \\
\end{array} \right)$.

$\det(A)=ad-bc$, $\det(B)=xt-yz$. $\det(A)\det(B)=(ad-bc)(xt-yz)=adxt-bcxt-adyz+bcyz$.
$AB=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
ax+bz & ay+bt \\
cx+dz & cy+dt  \\
\end{array} \right)$

$\det(AB)=(ax+bz)(cy+dt)-(ay+bt)(cx+dz)=axcy+bzcy+axdt+bzdt-aycx-btcx-aydz-btdz=bzcy+axdt-btcx-aydz=\det(A)\det(B)$, which concludes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

$\det(-)$ is the unique alternating multilinear function from $\Bbb R^2\times \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ for which $\det(e_1,e_2)=1$. In particular, if $f: \Bbb R^2\times \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ is multilinear alternating and $f(e_1,e_2)=\alpha$, $f=\alpha\det$. Show that for fixed $A$, $f(-)=\det(A-)$ is multilinear alternating and $f(e_1,e_2)=\det(A)$.